# Error while calling WEBSERVICE

Tags: jax-ws, soap-client

javax.net.ssl.trustStore is not defined
jul 23, 2018 12:01:29 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
ADVERTÊNCIA: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportBinding" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
jul 23, 2018 12:01:29 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
ADVERTÊNCIA: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl}UsingAddressing" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
jul 23, 2018 12:01:29 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
ADVERTÊNCIA: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: Erro de transporte HTTP: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Comment: describe the problem properly.

Comment: I'm trying to call WS SOAP from Lawyers Organization of a specific lawyer and evertime when I execute my code I have this error. I know that their WS require SOAP 1.2 and SSL. How can I solve this trouble?

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: The url is: https://www5.oab.org.br/Integracao/CNA.svc?wsdl

Comment: Calling method: consultaAdvogado("389330", null, null);

Comment: private static ArrayOfTOAdvogado consultaAdvogado(java.lang.String inscricao, java.lang.String uf, java.lang.String nome) {
        https.www5_oab_org_br.integracao.CNA service = new https.www5_oab_org_br.integracao.CNA();
        https.www5_oab_org_br.integracao.ICNA port = service.getWSHttpBindingICNA();
        return port.consultaAdvogado(inscricao, uf, nome);
    }

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you're having problems with English then https://www.deepl.com/translator should help. If you want an answer you really need to ask a question...